# Why Google indexed the preview URL of domain?

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, url, google-index

I have some problems when the web host updated the plesk desk and the server.

I looked to see which pages are indexed `site:www.charchas.gr` and then I looked for the preview `site:charchas.gr.193-92-107-8.linuxzone28.grserver.gr` *(this URL is to look the website if it does not yet have an associated domain name)*. Seems to have indexing 25 pages. 
Τhe question is why and how can block for the search results?

I use in *.htacess* this code but nothing changed.

```
RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.charchas.gr$ [nc]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.charchas.gr/$1 [r=301,nc,L]
```

Here is a preview of Cpanel[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why Google indexed the preview URL of domain?

Because Google found the URL; somehow! Emails, social media, etc. etc. I assume you are on a shared server(?) in which case there are probably others that are using a similar URL whilst developing their sites?

> I use in .htacess this code but nothing changed.

Presumably your **.htaccess** (two c's) code does redirect the "preview" URL to the live domain? (You have `RewriteEngine On` I assume?) In which case it will just *take time* for Google to reindex your site at the correct URL (assuming that is your intention).

## In the future...

To prevent your "preview" URL getting indexed you could perhaps password protect your site, or temporarily/conditionally set an `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header (one or two lines in .htaccess)?

To temporarily prevent your site from being indexed at all, you can add the following to .htaccess (remember to remove it when your site goes live!) in order to set an `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header (the equivalent of setting a robots meta tag on every resource).

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex,nofollow"
```

To conditionally set this header only when the "preview" URL is accessed you can try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [E=block:1]
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex,nofollow" env=block
```

Where `example.com` is your actual/live domain. In other words, only send this header when you access the site from a domain other than the live domain. This will allow your live site to be indexed, but block the "preview" URLs from being indexed. If you don't want your site to be indexed whilst you are developing it then you will need to use the *unconditional* version above.

The above directives set an environment variable (`block`) when accessing a domain other than `example.com` and only sets the `X-Robots-Tag` header when this environment variable is set.

Comment: Did you mean that in this IP193.92.107 used and other websites something like this
example-1.com.193-92-107-8.linuxzone28.grserver.gr

Comment: Yes. In fact doing a site search for `site:193-92-107-8.linuxzone28.grserver.gr` returns over 5,000 pages that appears to cover a handful of other domains.

Comment: yes I saw it and I hope that the .htacces file do the job

Comment: Sorry, but i forgot to ask. How to use X-Robots-Tag in htaccess. I have not  used it before and can not find something on the internet

Comment: @Charchas I've updated my answer with some examples.